# How can Bundler be inactive if it's appearing in my gem list?

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

Im trying to install this Rails project (https://github.com/mjohnson324/MockDoc/blob/master/docs/setup.md)

when running 'bundle install' I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.2) required by your /Users/michaelkoch/projects/MockDoc-master/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.2`
```

So I run 'gem install bundler:2.0.2' and the install seems to work. Here's the output:

```
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

If I run `gem list` I see the following line: `bundler (2.1.4, 2.0.2)`

If I run `bundle install` command again, I get the same orginal error, as if bundler is not installed.

I'm using rbenv to manage versions, as indicated by the Github project.
I kindly as for your help.

Comment: When you run ``% bundle version`` what version does it show?

Comment: Try to delete the `Gemfile.lock` file (do not worry Bundle is going to regenerate it) , make sure that you're running the right ruby version (2.6.0) running `rbenv version`. If not swicth to the right ruby version `rbenv local 2.6.0`. Then run  `gem install bundler:2.0.2` then run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue on my MacBook M1 system while trying to use 2.1.4 for my project. I tried deleting the gemfile.lock and reinstalling by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4` and then `bundle install` as suggested by @Giuseppe Schembri but that didn't solve my issue.

I navigated to the root directory, and tried to check the global version by running
`bundler version`
and got-

```
Bundler version 2.3.22 ([date] commit [commit_id])
```

I again navigated to my project directory, and ran `bundler version` again, and got -

```
Bundler version 2.1.4 ([date] commit [commit_id])
```

News flash: bundler 2.1.4 is installed for my project.

Then why does the error persist?

Aparently, I had a post-checkout file in my .git > hook which was trying to execute `bundler exec pod install` and failing.
Later I realized, it couldn't find the path for the bundler. so I get the path by running
`type bundler`
which returned

```
bundler is /Users/myUserName/.rbenv/shims/bundler
```

Then rather than bundler exec pod install, I used /Users/myUserName/.rbenv/shims/bundler exec pod install.

In the newer versions of OS on M1, this can happen.